# multiple graphs into single plot

Tags: matplotlib

i created six weibull distribution graphs and i would like to place them into one single plot in 3X2 layout
i have this so far:

```
cups_elev_and_azimuth=[['1','80.6','180'],['2','80.6','0'],['3','62.0','180'],['4','62.0','0'],['5','40.0','180'],['6','20.0','180']]
for i in cups_elev_and_azimuth:
    fig, ((ax1, ax2), (ax3, ax4),(ax5, ax6)) = plt.subplots(3, 2)
    plt.figure(i[0])
    a1, k, loc, c = stats.exponweib.fit(ws['an1 80.6m 180deg'],f0=1, floc=0)
    x = np.arange(0, 26, 0.1)
    y = stats.exponweib.pdf(x, a1, k, loc, c)
    f, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(5.5, 4))
    ax.hist(ws['an'+i[0]+' '+i[1]+'m '+i[2]+'deg'].dropna(), bins=26, range=(0,26),facecolor='none',    edgecolor='k', density=True, label='Data')
    ax.plot(x, y, 'b-', label='Weibull curve\n(k=%.3f, c=%.3f)' % (k, c))
    title=r'An'+i[0]+' Wind Speed Freq. Distr. at '+i[1]+'m, '+i[2]+'deg'+' '+site+' ('+ts+' - '+te+')'
    plt.title(title)
    plt.xlabel('Wind speed [m/s]')
    plt.ylabel('Frequency')
    ax.legend()
```

i cannot really figure out how to put the weibulls into their place (ax1-ax6). Every help is much appreciated, thanks!

Comment: You need to define the grid with `plt.subplots(3, 2)` only once, so that line should be outside of the loop. Within the loop, you don't need `plt.subplots()` at all, you can just assign plots to the axes you set up in the beginning.

Comment: How are we supposed to run this code without having access to all the variables? What is `ws`? Since you seem to be new to Stack Overflow, please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: point taken. ws is wind speed, it's a series and it's value is between 0 and 21. the length is 144